# How to monitor webpages for changes?

Tags: monitoring, internet, web

My company has a requirement to monitor a number of webpages for changes to content, with the ability to filter out parts of the pages we're not interested in.

Does anyone have experience of the best way to achieve this?

We have tried a number of solutions, but they all are either very buggy or just seem to miss changes completely.

Comment: 1) Could be helpful to list the software you’ve already tried. If you can, please [edit] your question. 2) Should it be a Web app or a local client? If local client, for which operating system(s)? 3) Does the solution have to support running JavaScript? 4) Do you have a budget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Smart WebMonitor](https://smartwebmonitor.com/WebMonitor) for monitoring changes to webpages, the email alerts are very useful. It stores a screenshot of the page for each change, which is useful.

It is already good at ignoring changes to sidebars etc. but you can filter out other parts of the page fairly easily as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, we'll trial this and some other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

What solution have you tried ?
If a minimum of human intervention is acceptable, the [firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/) plug-in [Update Scanner](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/update-scanner/) might just be what you're looking for.

> Features:
>
> - Select how often each site will be scanned
> - Changes to pages are highlighted automatically
> - Minor changes can be ignored
> - Full international support

cf. [their webpage](https://sneakypete81.github.io/updatescanner/) and [the support](https://github.com/sneakypete81/updatescanner/issues).

Comment: Thanks, I think we'll need a server based service, rather than a plugin.

Comment: Ok, very well, Francis, thanks for your comment. Two remarks: 1) you might consider [editing your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing) to reflect that aspect, and make it more precise, and 2) [upvoting answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is the best way to say "thank you".

Comment: It doesn't work on Twitter.

Comment: @Shayan I'm sorry it is not working for you. It's hard to understand why it would not be working from your message. What do you mean? It reports the page as having changed whereas it did not? Or it just does not report the page as having changed? You may want to look at the tickets open on Update's scanner repository with the keyword twitter, and see if one of them address your concern : https://github.com/sneakypete81/updatescanner/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+twitter